# UpdateProfile() during singup Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic2, firebase-authentication, angularfire

I'm working on an app and I want to achieve this.
When an user signing in I want to get his username and store in firebase.
So I created this :

```
Signup(email: string, password: string, displayName: string) {
    this.angFire.auth.createUser({
      email: email,
      password: password
    }).catch(
      (err) => {
        console.log(err);
        this.error = err;
      })
...
```

And this works, now I need to save also displayName into current user, so I try to do this inside the same function (Singup()) :

```
let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    user.updateProfile({
      displayName: this.displayName,
      photoURL: "https://example.com/jane-q-user/profile.jpg"
    }).then(function() {
      console.log("Nome utente inserito");
    }, function(error) {
      console.log("Errore durante inserimento utente");
    });
```

But it gives me this :

```
error_handler.js:54 EXCEPTION: Error in ./SignupPage class SignupPage - inline template:70:4 caused by: Cannot read property 'updateProfile' of null
```

How to do it? 
I'm running on ionic 2 angular2, firebase/angulrfire

Doc ref :

> Update a user's profile
>
> You can update a user's basic profile information—the user's display
>   name and profile photo URL—with the updateProfile method. For example:
>
> var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
>
> user.updateProfile({   displayName: "Jane Q. User",   photoURL:
>   "https://example.com/jane-q-user/profile.jpg" }).then(function() {
>   // Update successful. }, function(error) {   // An error happened. });

[Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users)

Comment: Posted in march but still no one gets the correct answer?

Comment: Did you update the displayName?

Answer (score 1):

My answer is way too late but just in case someone is interested, you could do it like this

```
  constructor(
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private router: Router
  ) { 
   //
  }


async signupUser(email: string, password: string): Promise<any> {
    const data = await this.afAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      email,
      password
    );
    return this.updateUserData(data.user).then(() => {
      this.router.navigate(["/"]);
    });
  }

 private updateUserData({ uid, email, photoURL, displayName }: User) {
    const userRef: AngularFirestoreDocument<User> = this.afs.doc(
      `users/${uid}`
    );
    return userRef.set({ uid, email, photoURL, displayName }, { merge: true });
 }
```

You can learn more [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qP5zw7fjQgo)